# Is there an event for onclick end?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, dom-events

I have a code in which should only be executed after an onclick event. On mobile devices its fine because I use touchstart and touchend. Is there an event similar to touchend for use on a computer?

My code currently looks similar to..

```
document.getElementById('trigger-box').addEventListener(function(e) {
    // the event will be used later
    // my code
});
```

I have tried searching the internet for an answer but unfortunately couldn't find an answer. Therefore, I have posted my question here.

Comment: @FabrizioMazzoni, indeed that is the answer.

Comment: I'd say [Onmousedown](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousedown.asp).

Comment: Yes. Like @FabrizioMazzoni said, uou can see a `click` as a sequence o `mousedown` and `mouseup` for the same element. So your _expires_ would be connected to the `mouseup`.

Comment: @FabrizioMazzoni thanks, this is exactly what i'm looking for. For some reason I read onkeydown (my mistake). Thank you very much

Comment: @IPAddress, but note onmouseup will execute **before** the onlclick executes. See the test in my answer

Comment: @AmmarCSE yeh but then you would use onmousedown?

Comment: @IPAddress, in the question, you stated you want code **after** a click event

Comment: @IPAddress, no, onmousedown will also execute before the click event

Comment: @AmmarCSE you and Fabrizio gave me the answer. And I am very happy for that Ammar. Hence, I have upvoted your answer :). But Fabrizio gave me the answer in the comments first so I have to accept his answer as the answer. I hope thats fair. But thanks for your good answer

Comment: @IPAddress, thats fine, you can accept his answer. But technically, it does not answer your question becuase you requested an event **after** the click event. His answer does not do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comment:

```
document.getElementById('trigger-box').addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
    // the event will be used later
    // my code
});
```

Comment: I believe it is necessary to use "touchend" on mobile.

Answer (score 4):

`onmouseup` happens **before** the `click` event is executed

```html
<button onclick="console.log(1)" onmouseup="console.log(2)">test</button>
```

Therefore, the only workaround I can think of is manually calling when the `click` event is completed

```js
function myClick()
{
  console.log('This is in click');
  afterClick();
}

function afterClick()
{
  console.log('This is after click');
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myClick()" >test</button>
```

Comment: hmm, it works but I really don't recommend embedded click events in HTML ... And please use `console.log(<String>)` for debug purposes

Comment: @KarelG, sorry if the alerts where annoying. Updated my answer to use console.log.